# redirecionar todas ar requisições para a index.php e pegar o valor passado pela URL

Tags: php, htaccess, single-page-application

Preciso redirecionar todas as requisição para a index.php para que possa inserir no body o arquivo .php correspondente a url.
Exemplo quando acesso o [www.dominio.com.br/esqueceu-senha](http://www.dominio.com.br/esqueceu-senha) carrego no index a pagina esqueceu-senha.php.
No index tem as tags <!doctype html>     , todos css,  e tambem todos os js. No da tag body carrego os arquivos .php. Simliar a uma spa.
criei o arquivo htacess conforme abaixo

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]


<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Plus-Sese-Br</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://localhost/app/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link href="http://localhost/app/vendor/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    
    
        
<?php 
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url']:'login.php';
$url = array_filter(explode('/',$url));
$file = $url[0].'.php';
if(is_file($file)){
    include_once $file;
}else{
    include_once 'login.php';
}   

?>
        
        
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/plus-outbound/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/plus-outbound/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

se o arquivo passado na url não existir é redireionado para login . Se o arquivo na url não existir esta funcionando. O problema esta quando existe a url / arquivo  não esta carregando entre a tag body como o exemplo. Estou usando url absulta em tudo mas quando a url passada existe carrega o arquivo somente este arquivo sem body css e js.

Comment: Parece que faltou fechar a tag <head> antes do <body>, não é isso? Ou ao postar esqueceu da tag?

Comment: foi so no postar que esqueci